# Where to find the organization ID for publishing apps privately in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, private

Where to find the organization ID for publishing apps privately in Play Store. Every link is showing about how to publish i cant find the proper way to get the organization ID.

Comment: you need to create an organization in Google My Business first. https://support.google.com/business/answer/7663063?hl=en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Determining your Organisation ID**

1. Sign into the managed Google Play Store (https://play.google.com/work)
2. Click ‘Admin Settings’ on the left-hand side (https://play.google.com/work/adminsettings)
3. The Organisation ID is given along with any other
   organisation information

*Note: Your account should be a Business Account .*

Comment: what happens if it is not a business account?